# null reference on deletion of an object

Tags: hibernate

I have an object A which has a reference B, when I am trying to delete A if the reference B is null, then its throwing not-null property reference .

Is there any way through annotations where I can mention that on deletion if the reference is null then ignore that while deleting the parent object.

sample is as below

```
@javax.persistence.ManyToOne( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY )
@javax.persistence.JoinColumn( name = "cmc_input1_tcl_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
@NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )
public TableColumn getInput1TableColumn() { return input1TableColumn; }
public void setInput1TableColumn( TableColumn val ) { this.input1TableColumn = val; }**
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature named OrphanRemoval that allows child objects to be removed from a relationship if the parent object is removed. But when there is no child there would be no problem!
Taking an eye over your sample it says nullable = false while you said the reference is null! Maybe this is the case...

Comment: yes, during save the nullable should be false , but while deleting it should ignore the null refernces.